# animate rect color change

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hey guys just wondering how I can make a smooth transition of a rects change in colour? So for example I have a basic grey rect background which I turn red, the problem is that the change in colour is instant. How can i do it so its a gradual change over seconds?

Here is my quick example. Cheers

```
local myRectangle = display.newRect(0, 0, 480, 320)
      myRectangle.strokeWidth = 3
      myRectangle:setFillColor(140, 140, 140)


local function changeColor() 
      myRectangle:setFillColor(240, 140, 140)   
end

timer.performWithDelay(2500, changeColor)
```

Comment: @krs You provided an answer, it should submitted as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you need transition, basically, you really can't do this with `transition.to` . You can do it with the help of an enterFrame listener and increment values for your R, G and B on each call.

Otherwise there is a sample code/library posted by **atoko** in corona forum. I haven't tried that personally, but you can check it here: http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/color-transition-wrapper

Keep Coding............ :)